# Extract value from xml string

Tags: c#, xml

Sorry for the trivial request, but it's a difficult time for me. I have this part of XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<structuredBody moodCode="EVN" classCode="DOCBODY">
  <component>
    <section ID="DESCRIPTION">
      <code code="57832-8" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" codeSystemVersion="2.19" />
      <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
      <text>
        <list ID="RQO">
          <caption>REQUEST:</caption>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prest_1">90153 - CORTISOLO [S]</content>
          </item>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prest_2">90171 - DEIDROEPIANDROSTERONE (DEA)</content>
          </item>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prest_3">90172 - DEIDROEPIANDROSTERONE SOLFATO (DEA-S)</content>
          </item>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prest_4">90413 - TESTOSTERONE [P]</content>
          </item>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prest_5">90414 - TESTOSTERONE LIBERO</content>
          </item>
        </list>
        <list ID="DIAG">
          <caption>Problem:</caption>
          <item>
            <content ID="Prob_1">Control</content>
          </item>
        </list>
      </text>
    </section>
  </component>      
</structuredBody>
```

I would need to get the values contained in the **text** tag, and in particular:
1) **Prest_1** 2) **90153 - CORTISOLO [S]**
and all the following lines. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So the question should be, "*how would I deserialize this xml?*", and my comment would be, "*what have you tried, what is not working for you?*". At that point you would say, "*i don't where to start*", to which id reply, "*try to search google first and then come back with parts that aren't working*". and then you would say, "*ok thanks*"

Comment: I'm using a class, HL7SDK.Xml.Cda, but I can't see the text tag, the last tag I see in the hierarchy is <section ID = "DESCRIPTION">. Obviously I tried to solve with google and other posts, but I did not succeed, also because I am not well but I have to finish the job. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: You are using Hl7 medal data So use schema at bottom of page : https://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public/wg/inm/datatypes-its-xml20050714.htm.  Locate the xsd.exe utility from Microsoft (download) which will automatically create the c# classes to use for serialization.  If you need help ask.  I've done lots of projects using HL7.  You can alos get additional info from : https://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=7

Comment: @jdwengI have a customer-supplied CDA.xsd file, which contains this code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:include schemaLocation="POCD_MT000040.xsd"/>
 <xs:element name="ClinicalDocument" type="POCD_MT000040.ClinicalDocument"/>
</xs:schema>
And I also have the POCD_MT000040.xsd file to which reference is made (I don't insert it because it's too big), but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: I don't know if it's the right way, but I generated a class from my cda.xsd, using xsd / classes / language: CS "cda.xsd" / outputdir: c: \ temp. He created me a .cs file which I am now going to examine to see how to use it.

Comment: With these few lines I can load the whole HL7 document, now I just have to find a way to read the <text> tag that I can't find.
            XmlSerializer myCda = new XmlSerializer(typeof(POCD_MT000040ClinicalDocument), Application.ExecutablePath);
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader("DATA.xml");
            POCD_MT000040ClinicalDocument myDocCda = (POCD_MT000040ClinicalDocument)myCda.Deserialize(myStreamReader);
            myStreamReader.Close();

Comment: download xsd.exe (see : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229875/install-xsdexe.html).  It may already be on you r machine.  the run from cmd.exe >.\xsd -l:cs -c POCD_MT000040.xsd.  The output is a POCD_MT000040.cs file which you add to your project.  You can then use XmlSerialization to read the xml file.

Comment: I just reading all your comments.  Looks like you are doing the correct thing.  All the deserialize data should be in the instance myDocCda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to XML makes it easy.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\temp\ClinicalDocument.xml";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    foreach (var el in doc.Descendants(ns + "content"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID='{0}', Content='{1}'", el.Attribute("ID").Value, el.Value);
    }
}
```

> Output

```
ID='Prest_1', Content='90153 - CORTISOLO [S]'
ID='Prest_2', Content='90171 - DEIDROEPIANDROSTERONE (DEA)'
ID='Prest_3', Content='90172 - DEIDROEPIANDROSTERONE SOLFATO (DEA-S)'
ID='Prest_4', Content='90413 - TESTOSTERONE [P]'
ID='Prest_5', Content='90414 - TESTOSTERONE LIBERO'
ID='Prob_1', Content='Control'
```